# alternative of getFormService() and getIdentifyService() in activi 7.x version

Tags: java, activiti

Earlier I was working on activiti 6.0.0 version and used org.activiti.engine.FormService and org.activiti.engine.IdentityService and called getFormService() adn getIdentityService(). but after upgrading to 7.1.4.M5 thosre classes are removed. can anyone help me with the alternative class or method for this files.

Comment: Any updates or workaround on this?